# Show estimated ~NNN rows count in SQLite EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

Tags: sqlite

There are several examples of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT ...` giving a result including the estimated number of rows accessed with `(~NNN rows)`.  The [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) gives an example:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT a, b FROM t1 WHERE a=1; 
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t1
```

And then says:

> The example above shows SQLite estimating that the full-table scan will visit approximately 100,000 records.

But it's not clear to me where that information about 100,000 rows is?

When I perform an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` it doesn't show the `(~NNN rows)` I have seen elsewhere even after running `ANALYZE`.  Is there an option or flag I can set somewhere?

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45 bda77dda9697c463c3d0704014d51627fceee328

$ sqlite
sqlite> .open master_db.sqlite
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM dk_table WHERE pk > 4;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE r2r_data USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid>?)
```

I'm hoping to see something like:

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE r2r_data USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid>?) (~200 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) also says:

> The details of the output format are subject to change from one release of SQLite to the next.

One of these changes removed the row count estimate.